# Limiting the Area Path to the top 3 levels, in a TFS query

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

We have a lot of area paths, some of which go down to level 6 or 7 (i.e. project\area\sub-area1\sub-area2\sub-area3\sub-area4\sub-area5).

Some tickets are assigned an area path to say project\area\sub-area1\sub-area2, whereas others are all the way down to sub-area5.

Is there a way to limit the number of levels to return in a TFS query? If I create a chart widget using area path, a lot of tickets come under 'other' as there are so many tickets under sub-area4/5 which get grouped up.

I could export to Excel and trim the area path, but I want to use the query on a dashboard inside Azure Dev Ops itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the query like as one of the following samples:

1. Limiting the area path to the top 3 levels means the work items you want to query should have one of the following area paths.

   - **`project\area`**
   - **`project\area\sub-area1`**
   - **`project\area\sub-area1\sub-area2`**

   So, you can set the query as below.

   **`Area Path`** **`=`** **`project\area`**

   **`Or`** **`Area Path`** **`=`** **`project\area\sub-area1`**

   **`Or`** **`Area Path`** **`=`** **`project\area\sub-area1\sub-area2`**

   [image]

   This query will return all the work items which have the area path **`project\area`**, **`project\area\sub-area1`** or **`project\area\sub-area1\sub-area2`**.
2. Limiting the area path to the top 3 levels means the work items you want to query should be not under the area path **`project\area\sub-area1\sub-area2\sub-area3`**.

   So, you can set the query as below.

   **`Area Path`** **`Not Under`** **`project\area\sub-area1\sub-area2\sub-area3`**

   [image]

   This query will return all the work items which is not under the the area path **`project\area\sub-area1\sub-area2\sub-area3`**.

   Under the area path **`project\area\sub-area1\sub-area2\sub-area3`** will include this area path and all its sub area paths.

Comment: The problem is that if I just did an `or | area path | =` at the level 3, I'd have about 50 or's. We have a lot of area paths.